# JavaScript, close tab when you open another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been looking for an answer for a good couple hours now so I've had to resort to coming here and asking for a bit of help.

The problem: I've got a couple href tags that open up a map or listings depending on what tab you click on, my problem being, I need to set the map as open by default and when you click on the listings tab, the map to close and open up the listings (so basically when you click on one, the other one closes and vice versa).

here's my code

HTML:

```
 <div class="clearfix"></div>
<a class="sortby">
    SORT BY
</a>
<a class="sortby_town" href="javascript:showDiv()">
    MAP
</a>
<a class="sortby_category" href="javascript:showListings()">
    LISTINGS
</a>

<div id="townmap" style="display: none; margin-top: 60px;">
{loadposition sawbridgeworth}
</div>

<div id="townlistings" style="display: none; margin-top: 60px;">
{component url='index.php?Itemid=132&option=com_mtree&task=search&searchword=Sawbridgeworth&cat_id=0'}
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function showDiv() {
document.getElementById('townmap').style.display = "block";
}

function showListings() {
document.getElementById('townlistings').style.display = "block";
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [jQuery Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) ?

It is a good plugin that will give you the functionality you are trying to create.

However, looking at your code why don't you simply have a line in there to hide the other div?

```
function showDiv() {
    document.getElementById('townmap').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('townlistings').style.display = "none";
}

function showListings() {
    document.getElementById('townlistings').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('townmap').style.display = "none";
}
```

`Diplay="none"` will hide the div. Alternatively if you are using jQuery (as your tag suggests) you can try the following :

```
function showDiv() {
    $('#townmap').show();
    $('#townlistings').hide();
}

function showListings() {
    $('#townlistings').show();
    $('#townmap').hide();
}
```

Comment: this works! i have no idea why i didn't think of using jQuery haha, i guess i just pulled a complete dumb moment and over complicated things! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **element.style.display = "none"**

```
function showDiv() {
document.getElementById('townmap').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('townlistings').style.display = "none";
}

function showListings() {
document.getElementById('townlistings').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('townmap').style.display = "none";
}
```

To show the map when the page loads, you can attach a function to the document, which will execute once the page has loaded

```
document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", function(){
    this.getElementById('townmap').style.display = "block";
});
```

I would always recommend using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) over pure JavaScript though. You should consider it if you haven't before, as you will find most things will take much less scripting than the way you are doing it now